# gcc-7 will not work with cross compiling when building linux kernel

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, kernel, building

gcc-7 isn't working when I am trying to build a linux kernel.

The command which I am using:

```
make export CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-7
```

Output:

> make: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-7gcc: Command not found

It has added gcc automatically after gnueabi- but not gcc-7 how do I stop it adding gcc automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CROSS_COMPILE` variable contains only the prefix needed for cross-compilation, apparently.

Most likely you can reset the `CC` variable to choose a different named compiler.  It's been a very long time since I tried to build the Linux kernel so I'm not sure, but something like this may work:

```
make export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- CC=gcc-7
```

Comment: It will not work, because in Makefile CC variable is defined like this: `CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc`

Comment: In that case,  use `make CC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-7` containing the entire path.